# PHP if page equals then echo DIV

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a div in my header that I only want to appear on the home page.

```
<div id="florida">
header content
</div>
```

The above example makes the div appear on every page. However if I put the following PHP it will show on every page apart from my 'work' page:

```
<div id="florida"><?php if ($page=="work") echo "</div>" ?>
header content
</div>
```

However I want it to appear only on the home page so naturally I attempted the following and got a syntax error.

```
<?php if ($page=="home") echo "<div id="florida">" ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at that syntax highlighting

Comment: Have a look at my answer Dan. Hope it helps you. `:)` Please accept if it does. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quotes confuse PHP:

```
<?php if ($page=="home") echo "<div id="florida">" ?>
<!-------------------------------------^-------^
```

Either you need to escape it using:

```
<?php if ($page=="home") echo "<div id=\"florida\">"; ?>
```

Or replace it with:

```
<?php if ($page=="home") echo '<div id="florida">'; ?>
```

Make sure, you give a `;` at the end of the statement.

Comment: (Semicolon not needed here, can be omitted)

Comment: @Rizier123 Just for a safety? `:)`

Comment: That worked perfectly, much appreciated! @Praveen Kumar